# Chartjs animate x-axis displaying data incorrectly in mac device

Tags: macos, chart.js

I am working with chartjs, I am trying to animate chart from right to left or left to right on load.

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('chart_canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Generate random data to plot
var DATA_POINT_NUM = 10;
var data = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [
        {
            data: [],
        },
    ]
}
for (var i=0; i<DATA_POINT_NUM; i++) {
    data.datasets[0].data.push(Math.random()*10);
    data.labels.push(String.fromCharCode(65+i));
}

var oldDraw = Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw;
Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw = function(animationFraction) {
    var animationConfig = this.chart.options.animation;
    if (animationConfig.xAxis === true) {
        var ctx = this.chart.chart.ctx;
        var hShift = (1-animationFraction)*ctx.canvas.width;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, hShift,0);
        if (animationConfig.yAxis === true) {
            oldDraw.call(this, animationFraction);
        } else {
            oldDraw.call(this, 1);
        }
        ctx.restore();
    } else if (animationConfig.yAxis === true) {
        oldDraw.call(this, animationFraction);
    } else {
        oldDraw.call(this, 1);
    }
}


var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: { 
        animation: { 
            duration: 5000,
            xAxis: true,
            yAxis: true,
        }
    }
});
```

[Example 1](https://jsfiddle.net/16L8sk2p/)

The above code works fine on windows, but I'm facing issue on mac devices.While animating from left to right the data displays incorrectly means that the data moves to upward from x axis.How to fix this issue?
I am attaching screenshot.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLKbr.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change `setTransform` to `transform`.
Try the following code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('chart_canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Generate random data to plot
var DATA_POINT_NUM = 10;
var data = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [
        {
            data: [],
        },
    ]
}
for (var i=0; i<DATA_POINT_NUM; i++) {
    data.datasets[0].data.push(Math.random()*10);
    data.labels.push(String.fromCharCode(65+i));
}

var oldDraw = Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw;
Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw = function(animationFraction) {
    var animationConfig = this.chart.options.animation;
    if (animationConfig.xAxis === true) {
        var ctx = this.chart.chart.ctx;
        var hShift = (1-animationFraction)*ctx.canvas.width;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, 1, hShift,0);
        if (animationConfig.yAxis === true) {
            oldDraw.call(this, animationFraction);
        } else {
            oldDraw.call(this, 1);
        }
        ctx.restore();
    } else if (animationConfig.yAxis === true) {
        oldDraw.call(this, animationFraction);
    } else {
        oldDraw.call(this, 1);
    }
}


var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',
data: data,
options: { 
animation: { 
duration: 5000,
xAxis: true,
yAxis: true,
}
}
});
```